# real world example of two variables that cannot explain a dependent variable univariately but perfectly explain the dependent variable jointly

Tags: regression, linear

An interesting statistical curiosity I like is the following:

Suppose you have 3 non-random variables X, Y and Z.
Suppose that univariately X & Y can explain 2% and 5% of the variation in Z respectively.
The theoretical upper bound of how much of the variance you can explain in Z in a multivariate regression with X & Y is 100%.

Does anyone have any intuitive explanation for why this is the case, or even better can think of a real world example of this unintuitive fact?

Comment: Geometrically this says $X$ and $Y$ could generate the plane in which $Z$ lies ("100%") yet each could make nearly right angles with $Z.$  What's not intuitive about that?  Indeed, one of them might make a perfect right angle with $Z$ (0% variance explained).  Example: take $(X,Z)$ to be orthogonal variables (uncorrelated) and set $Y=X+\lambda Z$ for arbitrary $\lambda \ne 0.$  That alone suggests where to look for examples in data sets (specifically, where one of the explanatory variables is expected to be unassociated with the response).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider a room of slot machines at a casino, with observations of each visitor.

Let $X$ be the money that a visitor puts in the slot machines.

Let $Y$ be the money that the visitor gets out of the slot machines.

Let $Z$ be the visitor’s net profits at the slot machines, so $Z=X-Y$.

Then $X$ has low correlation with $Z$, since people who bet a lot can both win big and lose big. Similarly $Y$ has low correlation with $Z$. But together $X$ and $Y$ explain $Z$ perfectly.

Comment: Perfect intuitive example - thank you!